# Python code readability assistance

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-slicing

I would like to improve my code's readability and formatting. I have this code, that works, but I feel like it could be tighter than this, I just can't seem to get it to work any other way.  The idea is to read a .txt file find incoming e-mail strings and organize the data by frequency of hour sent.

Here is an example line that I'm looking for in the text:

> From email@emailaddress.com Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008

Here is my code as it is today.

```
fname = input("Enter file:")
if len(fname) <1 : fname = "mbox-short.txt"
fh = open(fname)
time = list()
hours = list()
hr = dict()

for line in fh:
        if not line.startswith("From "): continue
        words = line.split()
        time.append(words[5])

for i in time:
        i.split(":")
        hours.append(i[:2])

for h in hours:
        hr[h]=hr.get(h, 0)+1

l = list()
for k,v in hr.items():
        l.append((k,v))
l.sort()
for k, v in l:
        print (k,v)
```

Comment: if this code is working, bring it to [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), they are better suited for what you want

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know Code review SE was a thin... told you I was new..

Comment: for one thing, remember to close the file... or learn how to use `with`

Comment: Check out `DictReader`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: you can also use a regex matcher to group your different fields

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a somehow anonymised input-file containg sample data additionally.

Comment: When i ran you codes with the sample email address I a tuple ('09', 1) what does "1" mean/signify..isn't it ascending hours only you need?

Answer (score 1):

Here's (what I think is) functionally equivalent code:

```
from collections import Counter

fname = input("Enter file: ")
if fname == "":
    fname = "mbox-short.txt"

hour_counts = Counter()
with open(fname) as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith("From "):
            continue
        words = line.split()
        time = words[5]
        hour = time[:2]
        hour_counts[hour] += 1

for hour, count in sorted(hour_counts.items()):
    print(hour, count)
```

You might also want to parse mbox format with an existing Python library, instead of doing it yourself.

Comment: I ran this with my file and it works perfectly. Using with and counter are new to me, but they make perfect sense.  Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Just some hint : (Don't try this at home, it's really bad code :D, but show some python structs to learn) (operator, defaultdict and list comprehension)

```
from collections import defaultdict
import operator

hr = defaultdict(int)

with open(fname) as fh:
    hours = [data.split()[5].split(":")[:2] for data in fh if data.startswith("From ")]

for h in hours:
    hr[h]+=1

sorted_hr = sorted(hr.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1))
for k, v in sorted_hr:
        print (k,v)
```

Comment: Also demonstrates `with` statements, which every Python programmer should know and use religiously. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**A regex approach will be something like this**

```
import re
hours=[]
with open("new_file") as textfile:
    for line in textfile:
        if re.search("^From [A-Za-z0-9]+[@][a-zA-Z]+[.][a-z]{3}",line):
            hours.append(re.sub(".*([0-9]{2})[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2} [0-9]{4}.*","\\1",line.strip()))

hours.sort()               
print(hours)
```

**Example** 
if the data below is in a file `new_file`

```
kwejrhkhwr
From johnking@emailaddress.com Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008
From JohnPublic@emailaddress.com Sat Dec 31 01:40:16 2015
Something not needed here
Something not needed here
From JohnPublic125@emailaddress.com Sat Oct 25 44:03:10 2015
```

**Output** of hours in ascending order

```
['01', '09', '44']
```